# PHPStorm SVN Error

Tags: php, svn, tortoisesvn, phpstorm

I have integrated PHPStorm - SVN repository and I can do commit/update without any problem. But I always get an error with the message when I do any change on any file(s):

> Some errors occurred while accessing svn working copy database.

I think reason for that message is inability to find `svn.exe`. I have installed SlikSVN to find `svn.exe` and from:

`Settings -> Version Control -> Subversion -> General tab` checked `"Use command line client"`

and also set current directory of `svn.exe` (C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\svn.exe). But I still get that message!

NOTE : I have also installed the TortoiseSVN.

Comment: what is your working copy version? I'd suggest creating a support ticket, attaching the screenshots of your settings and idea.log

Comment: how to get this information?

Comment: idea.log: Help | Show log in the IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling your OS in English.